# Why is my Azure AD application not authorized to grant free products?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, windows-10-universal

I'm following the [Grant free products](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/grant-free-products) documentation. My goal is to grant existing users of our Microsoft Store apps a free IAP.

First, I need to generate a token to pass to the client, so it can use it to create a Microsoft Store ID client-side. I do this every 15 minutes. Here's how I'm generating this ID:

```
## POST location:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[...snip...]/oauth2/token

## Headers:
{
  'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.19.1',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Content-Length': '222',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

## Body:
grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=[...snip...]
&client_secret=[...snip...]
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fonestore.microsoft.com%2Fb2b%2Fkeys%2Fcreate%2Fpurchase
```

I get a valid-looking token back, which I pass to the client. The client then successfully generates a Microsoft Store ID and passes it back to my service.

In the service, I generate another token:

```
## POST location:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[...snip...]/oauth2/token

## Headers:
{
  'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.19.1',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Content-Length': '189',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

## Body:
grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=[...snip...]
&client_secret=[...snip...]
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fonestore.microsoft.com
```

Using this token and the Microsoft Store ID, I attempt to grant a free product:

```
## POST location:
https://purchase.mp.microsoft.com/v6.0/purchases/grant

## Headers:
{
  'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.19.1',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ[...snip..]', # Generated in the preceding step
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Host': 'purchase.mp.microsoft.com',
  'Content-Length': '1837'
}

## Body:
{
  "b2bKey": "eyJ0eXA[...snip...]", # Microsoft Store ID generated client-side
  "availabilityId": "9S2VX8BJ70P6", # retrieved client-side
  "productId": "9ND65B119C8N", # the Store ID of a free in-app purchase
  "skuId": "0010", # retrieved client-side
  "language": "en-us",
  "market": "ca",
  "orderId": "7a75b5a2-060d-46a1-b5d3-cec646303b52" # new UUID each request
}
```

This request gets a 401 response with the following content:

```
  {
    "code":"Unauthorized",
    "data":[],
    "details":[],
    "innererror":{
      "code":"ClientIdNotAuthorized",
      "data":["ClientId","[...snip...]"],
      "details":[],
      "message":"The client id specified in request is not authorized to use this resource",
      "source":"PurchaseFD"
    },
    "message":"The client is not authorized to perform the requested operation.",
    "source":"PurchaseFD"
  }
```

The associated Azure AD app is registered to the dev account in the Windows Developer Dashboard. As per the docs, it has the following identifierUris section:

```
"identifierUris": [
  "https://onestore.microsoft.com/b2b/keys/create/purchase",
  "https://onestore.microsoft.com/b2b/keys/create/collections",
  "https://onestore.microsoft.com/"
],
```

#### Things I've tried:

When I change the skuId or availabilityId to a garbage value, I get a 'Requested catalog product data was not found' 400 error, which hints that my authorization token is valid for at least *some* things...

Sending a POST to `https://purchase.mp.microsoft.com/v8.0/b2b/recurrences/query` (following [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-subscriptions-for-a-user)) with the exact same token results in a `200 OK` response with content `{"items":[]}`, as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you call `StoreContext.GetCustomerPurchaseIdAsync()` method to get the b2bkey, you need to pass access token to this method. This token is created with the `https://onestore.microsoft.com/b2b/keys/create/purchase` audience URI.  Please check the resource value in request body when you post request to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/token`.

Comment: Hi @XavierXie-MSFT , thanks for responding! The access token I'm passing to `StoreContext.GetCustomerPurchaseIdAsync()` was indeed created with the resource URI `https://onestore.microsoft.com/b2b/keys/create/purchase`, as per the docs. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I've added more detail, hopefully that helps! Would be grateful for any further direction you can offer.

Comment: Hi @ductionist, have you ever received _non-empty items_ from "Get subscriptions of a user" or "Query for products" API? We always get `200 OK response with content {"items":[]}`, same result as your mentioned in your post, but never any actual purchase or subscription. Here are more details: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51968616/1664795.

Comment: @mikejd I haven't, but we haven't started working with subscriptions yet - good luck getting that issue solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From someone at Microsoft:

> I'm sorry you encountered this problem. This problem was apparently caused by a service-side bug that was fixed last week[...].